# Magento customer registration not saving selected state/region

Tags: attributes, customer, register

So for some reason my Magento install (1.5) stopped saving new customers state/region name, both inside admin and outside.

Magento's `registration form` has a `dropdown select`, with a name of `"region_id"` and a hidden text field named `"region"`. I guess that some javascript is supposed to get the selected name and set the "region" field, but that doesn't work.

What I did was create a jQuery line that, on form submit, gets the region name and sets the "region" field to it. That works, somewhat. There are still customers who are registering without a region name, only the id.

Anyone ever had something similar?

Comment: do you use a custom template? have you made any changes to the registration process or the customer attributes?

Comment: I use de default template, I know it's terrible, but it was an inherited project. There has been no change to customer attributes, and the only change I did to the template was adding the jquery script to give it a quick fix.

Comment: Follow [this guide](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/361) and report back.

Comment: Well, it's already in production. And it isn't a php error, because error reporting is on.

Answer (score 2):

There is a table `customer_form_attribute` which links the customer and customer address attributes to the forms in your website. There should be an entry in this table for the attribute `region_id`. Note: in the sample data this is `attribute_id` 13.

Without this entry the attribute will not be saved when the form is processed. The attribute will not be picked up when the `extractData` in the class `Mage_Customer_Model_Form` and so it will be ignored when extracting the data from the request into the `$addressData`.

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php

$addressForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
$addressForm->setFormCode('customer_address_edit')
    ->setEntity($address);
$addressData    = $addressForm->extractData($this->getRequest());
$addressErrors  = $addressForm->validateData($addressData);
if ($addressErrors !== true) {
    $errors = $addressErrors;
}
```